# Modifying Array instances self with external Array method

Tags: arrays, ruby, yield

While practicing ruby, I wrote a class such like that:

```
class Array

  def my_each
    c = 0
    until c == size
      yield self[c]
      c += 1
    end
  end

  def my_map
    c = 0
    acc = []
    my_each {|e| acc << yield(e)}
    acc
  end

end

def plus_two(a)
  a += 2
end

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
nums.my_map {|e| plus_two(e)}

p nums
```

*It works great and expected*. However, I want to implement the `Array#my_map!` which modifies the instance and I could not figure out how to modify the existing array in that way.

As far as I know (I'm a beginner Ruby developer has experience on Java) we can access the instance variables by `@` but in that case, I could not figure out the best practice. What's the decent way to solve scenarios like that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you increment `c`, you could use `self[c] = new_value` to set the value at index `c`

Comment: `c` is the iterator index. We are iterating over self instance to yield objects one by one.

Comment: Yes and you could store the result from `yield` back to the array via `self[c] = …`.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a `Array#my_map!` method like in the below:

```
  def my_map!
    self.replace(my_map {|e| yield(e)})
  end
```

So we need to replace the instance (self) with our new temporary instance. Works well.

Comment: `my_map` is not defined. I presume you mean `class Array; def my_map!; self.replace(map {|e| yield(e)}); end; end`, in which case `self.` is redundant, but does no harm. That is, the operative line can be written `replace(map {|e| yield(e)})`. However, this does not always produce the same result as does `Array#map!`. Suppose `a = [1,2,3]`. Then `a.my_map! { |e| e.to_f/a.sum }; a #=> [0.166..., 0.333..., 0.5]`. By contrast,...

Comment: ...`a = [1,2,3]; a.map! { |e| e.to_f/a.sum }; a #=> [0.166..., 0.387..., 0.844...]`.  As you see, `map!`, unlike `my_map!` is changing elements of `a` one-by-one, which affects `a.sum`. You need to incorporate @Stefan's suggestions.

Comment: The advantage that the bang methods take over the non-banged is that they save the execution time that is needed to make a copy. Therefore, the `replace` approach is counteractive. The better reproduction is the `self[c]=...` solution and letting the non-bang version just call `dup` followed by the bang-version.

Comment: @CarySwoveland my_map is defined in the class that I mentioned in question. However, your answer perfectly clears my confusion :). Thank you!

Comment: @bertramscharpf I've modified the method as you say. Thanks for you help.